# Heroku пишет, что aiogram не поддерживается python 3.6, хотя при запуске через компьютер всё работает?

Tags: python, heroku, aiogram

Написал телеграм бота с помощью фреймвока aiogram и решил залить его на хостинг Heroku. Теперь когда я запускаю через этот хостинг выдаёт ошибку:

`ImportError: Your Python version 3.6.12 is not supported by aiogram, please install Python 3.7+`

Значит python 3.6 не поддерживвает aiogram, но когда я запускал просто через компьютер, с консоли то никаких ошибок не было. Почему так? И как решить проблему, нужно обновить питон на компьютере или можно по другому?

Comment: Оказываеттся у меня на компьютере установлен python 3.7.4, но почему heroku говорит о 6 версии??

Answer (score 2):

Потому что на Heroku стоит Python 3.6.12.

---

Решение для Ubuntu (как пример):

Шаг 1: Обновляемся

```
 sudo apt update
```

Шаг 2: Устанавливаем вспомогательное ПО для PPA

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
```

Шаг 3: Добавляем Deadsnakes PPA и обновляемся

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt update
```

Шаг 4: Устанавливаем Python 3.8 и проверяем

```
sudo apt install python3.8
python ––version
```

Шаг 5: Выставляем Python 3.8 как основной

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```